# SVN errors when opeinig project in Android studio

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, android-studio

I have a project under Subversion hosted in Assembla, which I have checked out using TortoiseSVN. the project is now in my local folder on my computer.
Now, I open Android studio, click open a project and the studio opens my project.

However I get the following errors

**Can't use Subversion command line client: svn**

**Errors found while svn working copies detection**

When I click 'Fix it' there is a window saying 'No items to show'

[image: Errors]
When I click on Fix it button, it opens the the Settings of Subversion
[image]

Anyone has any idea how can I fix them?

Comment: did you get solution of this issue, if you get solution then please let me know.. manoj.kb2011@gmail.com It's my mail id.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can also read this in your screen-shot:

> Can't use Subversion command line client: svn
>   Probably the path to Subversion executable is wrong. Fix it.

You're apparently assuming that your IDE works on top of TortoiseSVN and that isn't the case. You need to install the Subversion **command-line client**. TortoiseSVN actually bundles it, but it's an optional component.

In more general terms, Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA, which is a Java-powered IDE that bundles its own Subversion client. Most likely, you are using latest TortoiseSVN and it created a Subversion 1.8 working copy. Most Java-based IDEs do not support 1.8 yet. Perhaps it allows to use the command-line client as workaround.

Solutions:

- Get an older TortoiseSVN
- Wait for a newer Android Studio
- Install the command-line client as the program suggests

---

**Edit:** apparently, it isn't entirely clear how to install the command-line client packed with TortoiseSVN. Here's a screen-shot from the installation wizard I found in Google images (it shouldn't be very different from latest release):

[image: *.msi]

You need to click on the little rectangle with the red cross to the left of "command line client tools" and select "This component will be available" (or a similar text). Then click *Next* until you're done.

Comment: May you give a link from where I can install command-line client?

Comment: [Sure](https://www.google.es/search?q=tortoisesvn&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:es-ES:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=d6pGU421A-nQ8gfEmICgCQ)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you click on "Fix it"?

Comment: edited the question please take a look

Comment: That looks promising then. If it doesn't detect it you've installed it, you can enable it at that dialogue.

Comment: the link you gave is the link to TortoiseSVN. I already have it and do not want to downgrade, I wish to install the command line client

Comment: I've edited my answer to post a screen-shot. If you still can't get it, perhaps you can try another IDE until yours get upgraded. NetBeans already supports 1.8 and it has an [Android plug-in](http://nbandroid.org/).

Comment: i am looking for a solution for 1 hour, this was it! thanks!